# React hydration on SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am not fully understood React's `Server Side Rendering`. 
What's difference behaviors occurred between two examples?

**First**

```
function Test() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext)
  const { user } = context

  return (
    user ? <h1>User</h1> : <h1>No User</h1>
  )
}

export default withApollo({ ssr: true })(Test)
```

===> Error occured ***Text content did not match. Server: "No User" Client: "User"***

**Second**

```
function Test() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
     setUser(context.user)
  }, [])

  return (
    user ? <h1>User</h1> : <h1>No User</h1>
  )
}

export default withApollo({ ssr: true })(Test)
```

===> No Error.

What's difference? Why the first one make error but second not? In Postman, when I request this component route for checking server side response, both's response are same (No User).

What point is make difference? useEffect only excuted in client side, I know, but how about first one also updated to No User to User. when is hydration point, render point ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't be 100% on this without seeing how `AuthContext` is set up on both client and server renders, but following logically backwards it seems like the difference here is that `AuthContext` is already populated with a value before the client's first render, but not before the server render.

That's why in the first example your server render contains no user, but your first client render contains a user. No user populated in `AuthContext` on the server, `AuthContext` populated with user on the client, so first client render is different from the server render hence the error.

In the second example, because you're reading `user` from state which is only set from the `AuthContext` *after* the first client render using `useEffect`, the first render on the client *also* contains no user - hence no difference between server render, and first client render, and no error.